# reseted .bash_profile, but forgot add export then cannot find .bash_profile. now basics command not found. how to fix?

Tags: bash

Mistook change `.bash_profile`, so I tried to reset `.bash_profile`.

By open the `/.bash_profile or /.profile` file from the recent menu.
After opening it, reset the path to its default by typing export `PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin` and save the file and close.

But didn't add export during reset.

Now basics command not found and can't find `.bash_profile`.

How to fix..?

Comment: Welcome to SO, did you reloaded bash_profile? If not then please do it; we are supposed to reload it in case of any changes made to it and you want to reflect those changes within same session of box.

Comment: Hi. In BASH you do not need `export`. If your commands are gone type in your terminal PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin . By default .bash_profile does not exists. To make changes available you have to relaod a terminal.